# Trying to call a function using onclick

Tags: javascript

I have created a function to create a table and have populated it with questions.  I have tried to create a button to bring the table but it seems to not be working.  Anyone know what I have missed?

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="createSheet()">Display</button>   
</body>
<script>
  var totalQuestions;
  function createSheet() {
    var sheet = "";
    totalQuestions = 8;

    sheet += "<div><table>";
    for (var i = 0; i < totalQuestions; i++) {
      sheet += "<tr>";
      sheet += "<td class='question'>";
      sheet += "<div class='questionNumber'>" + "A" + (i + 1) + "</div>";
      sheet += "<div class='qContent'>" + addition2() + " </div>";
      sheet += "</td>";
      sheet += "<td class='question'>";
      sheet += "<div class='questionNumber'>" + "B" + (i + 1) + "</div>";
      sheet += "<div class='qContent'>" + addition2() + " </div>";
      sheet += "</td>";
      sheet += "<td class='question'>";
      sheet += "<div class='questionNumber'>" + "C" + (i + 1) + "</div>";
      sheet += "<div class='qContent'>" + addition2() + " </div>";
      sheet += "</td>";
      sheet += "</tr>";
    }
    
    return sheet;
    sheet += "</table></div>"; 
  }
        
  function addition2() {
    var difficulty = 1000;
    var ans;
        
    for (var i = 0; i < totalQuestions; i++) {
      var numGen = Math.round(Math.random() * difficulty + 100);
      var numGen1 = Math.round(Math.random() * difficulty + 100);
      var question = numGen  +  " + "  +  numGen1
      var ans = numGen + numGen1
    } 
    
    return question;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: 1. of all please fix the indentation of your code, 2. You are returning sheet which will just cause it to get lost as the return value of event handlers basically just get lost

Comment: You don't do anything with the results of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose what you are trying to do is display a table when the button is clicked:

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="createSheet()">Display</button> 
  <div id="tableContainer">
  </div>  
</body>
<script>
  var totalQuestions;
  function createSheet() {
    var sheet = "";
    totalQuestions = 8;

    sheet += "<div><table>";
    for (var i = 0; i < totalQuestions; i++) {
      sheet += "<tr>";
      sheet += "<td class='question'>";
      sheet += "<div class='questionNumber'>" + "A" + (i + 1) + "</div>";
      sheet += "<div class='qContent'>" + addition2() + " </div>";
      sheet += "</td>";
      sheet += "<td class='question'>";
      sheet += "<div class='questionNumber'>" + "B" + (i + 1) + "</div>";
      sheet += "<div class='qContent'>" + addition2() + " </div>";
      sheet += "</td>";
      sheet += "<td class='question'>";
      sheet += "<div class='questionNumber'>" + "C" + (i + 1) + "</div>";
      sheet += "<div class='qContent'>" + addition2() + " </div>";
      sheet += "</td>";
      sheet += "</tr>";
    }
    
    // return sheet; !! return over here will stop the function from continuing
    sheet += "</table></div>"; 

    document.getElementById("tableContainer).innerHtml = sheet;
  }
        
  function addition2() {
    var difficulty = 1000;
    var ans;
        
    for (var i = 0; i < totalQuestions; i++) {
      var numGen = Math.round(Math.random() * difficulty + 100);
      var numGen1 = Math.round(Math.random() * difficulty + 100);
      var question = numGen  +  " + "  +  numGen1
      var ans = numGen + numGen1
    } 
    
    return question;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks I had tried  the fixes you suggested before but had not removed the return.  Learning something every day.

Comment: When I try this the .innerHtml = sheet; is returning an error of invalid token